# SWT Browser Widget using XULRunner 10 need to print pages in colour

Tags: java, swt, xulrunner

I am using the SWT (version 4.3) Browser widget with XULRunner 10 on Windows.  I need to print out dashboards from the browser widget in colour i.e. Browser to print background images and colours.  I have investigated and/or tried unsuccessfully a few ways to get pages to print with colour, such as: -

1. put MozillaInterfaces.jar in the classpath and do browser.getWebBrowser().  This returns null
2. Edit the prefs.js and update the printer entries related to printing colours.  Does this file only get ready by Mozilla Browser Widget when a Mozilla Browser Widget is created?
3. Use reflection to get the nsIPrefBranch
4. Use javascript to get the nsIPrefBranch

My solution now is to launch a new Browser Widget using IE (SWT.NONE) as a print window and then call the javascript print function.

Thanks for any suggestions and help

Comment: Oh man, if you received an answer that would be great. When I hear `SWT Browser` and `XULRunner` I die a little inside, each time.